# Empty editText field shows error on all fields [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

i have five editText fields and i want to validate if there is empty editText. 
my code is working, the problem is that when there is one empty field, error shows on all fields.

here is my code:

```
            String one = firstname.getText().toString();
            String two = lastname.getText().toString();
            String three = email.getText().toString();
            String four = address.getText().toString();
            String five = mobile.getText().toString();

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(one) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(two) &&
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(three) &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(four) &&
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(five)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(main.this, next.class);
                i.putExtra("first", one);
                i.putExtra("last", two);
                i.putExtra("email", three);
                i.putExtra("mobile", four);
                i.putExtra("address", five);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                firstname.setError("First name cannot be empty");
                lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
                email.setError("email cannot be empty");
                address.setError("address cannot be empty");
                mobile.setError("mobile cannot be empty");

            }
```

Comment: that's because your else statement is wrong. It's showing exactly what you wrote in your code. You need to improve your else statement ;)

Comment: hi @Umair i'm new to android development, it will be better if you post a working code, thank you :)

Comment: working answers are already posted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Boolean valid = true;
if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(one) ) {
    firstname.setError("First name cannot be empty");
    valid = false;
} 

if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(two) ) {
    lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
    valid = false;
}

if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(three) ) {
    email.setError("email cannot be empty");
    valid = false;
}

if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(four) ) {
    address.setError("address cannot be empty");
    valid = false;
}

if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(five) ) {
    mobile.setError("mobile cannot be empty");
    valid = false;
}

if ( valid ) {
   Intent i = new Intent(main.this, next.class);
   i.putExtra("first", one);
   i.putExtra("last", two);
   i.putExtra("email", three);
   i.putExtra("mobile", four);
   i.putExtra("address", five);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much :) its working,  BTW you forget to add ")" in if statements.

Answer (score 0):

you doing if checks on everything at once, do it separately like this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(main.this, next.class);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(one)) {
            i.putExtra("first", one);
        } else {
            firstname.setError("First name cannot be empty");
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(two)) {
            i.putExtra("last", two);

        } else {
            lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
        }
        ......
```

Comment: It will trigger startActivity even if there are empty values. I guess the OP wouldn't want that.

Comment: It depends what do you want, you can modify code. Answer is just why you seeing errors on all fields instead of one :)

Answer (score 0):

Because in `else` case you are setting error on every field -

```
            firstname.setError("First name cannot be empty");
            lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
            email.setError("email cannot be empty");
            address.setError("address cannot be empty");
            mobile.setError("mobile cannot be empty");
```

-------------------------above is wrong ---------------------

For specific try separating the if case like below -

```
if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(one) ) {
    firstname.setError("First name cannot be empty");
}
if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(two) {
    lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
}

......and so on.
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple example where you can reuse code in this particular case.

```java
...
//Usage
 if(validate(firstname,"First name") && validate(lastname, "last name") &&
                    validate(email,"email") &&validate(address,"address") &&
                    validate(mobile,"Mobile")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(main.this, next.class);
                i.putExtra("first", one);
                i.putExtra("last", two);
                i.putExtra("email", three);
                i.putExtra("mobile", four);
                i.putExtra("address", five);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        // No need of else statement

....
// Create this method somewhere in your activity
boolean validate(EditText editText, String label){

     if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())){
           editText.setError(label+" cannot be empty");
           return false;
     }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the basic logic where you are doing wrong, your code is saying 
>   if anyone from these four ( one, two , three , four ) is empty then your if statement will o execute, else statement will execute, so in else all your edit text will show error. So now you need to check like this,

```
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(one)) {
        i.putExtra("first", one);
    } else {
        firstname.setError("First name cannot be empty");
        return;
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(two)) {
        i.putExtra("last", two);

    } else {
        lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
        return;
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(three)) {
        i.putExtra("last", three);

    } else {
        lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
      return;
    }
     if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(four)) {
        i.putExtra("last", four);

    } else {
        lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
       return;
    }
   if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(five)) {
        i.putExtra("last", five);

    } else {
        lastname.setError("last name cannot be empty");
        return;
    }
```